# Injecting IDbConnectionFactory into Service class

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I have started using ServiceStack today. So, let me know if I am doing something completely wrong.

I am trying to inject Db into my Service class, for which I am using this code

```
[TestFixture]
public class UserServiceTests
{
    private UserService service;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var appHost = new BasicAppHost();
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", false, SqliteDialect.Provider);
        appHost.Container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
        service = new UserService();
        service.SetAppHost(appHost);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Calling_post_method_with_valid_User_saves_it_in_database()
    {
        var User = new User { Name = "Acme Limited" };
        var id = service.Post(User);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, id);
    }
}
```

There are two problems:
1) I am getting exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.82.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? And do we really need SQLite for testing, is there is Fake object available?

2) The compiler is warning about - service.SetAppHost(appHost). SetAppHost is depricated.
How can I inject Db into my service class without using SetAppHost?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a platform incompatibility issue with Sqlite, make sure you're using the right Sqlite package for your machine.

As for `service.SetAppHost(appHost)` the [deprecated message](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L31) says to use `service.SetResolver(appHost)` as **IAppHost** also implements `IResolver`, so use that.

Comment: Thanks! With OrmLite.Sqlite, NuGet installed version 1.0.84. But OrmLite was probably looking for version 1.0.82. Updated to required version to get it working.